# Visa from Italy and return from Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, italy, return-tickets, return

I am not an EU citizen. I wonder if I get a Schengen visa from Italy and a flight to Milan, is it okay if my return flight is from Frankfurt?

Comment: The answer depends on what information you put in your visa application and on whether departing from Frankfurt is a significant change from those plans.  If you want to add those details along with the reason for the change, you'll likely get more useful answers.

Answer (score 7):

A single-entry visa may only be used for the purpose for which it was granted, but you can **make minor adjustments** to the itinerary after the visa is granted. Of course you may not **misrepresent your plans** in the hope that this makes a visa more likely. The risk would be that a honest adjustment *after* the visa was granted is seen as deception *before* during the application.

- If you fly from Italy to Frankfurt and just transit there to your final destination, there should be no problem. Changing flights, including changing layovers, is allowed by the Schengen rules.
- If you travel from Italy to Germany halfway through your trip and if you spend much time in Germany, this could be problematic even if you spend *slightly* more time in Italy than in Germany.

You can and should mention your point of entry and exit in the application. If that is done, and if the visa gets approved on that basis, you should be fine. (If you would, for example, plan a visit in Greece with layover in Iceland, there would be questions which your application needs to answer.)

Answer (score 1):

> it okay if my return flight is from Frankfurt?

Provided your main destination is not Germany, you'll have absolutely no issues

Comment: -1 You may enter/exit the Schengen Area at any border crossing point. It doesn't matter what your your main destination is.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Sure, but if you misrepresent your trip to get a Italian visa, that's not legal

Comment: This question is only about if it is it okay if the return flight is through another member state. The main destination is not effected by this.